# Help building up LINQ2SQL query which has joins

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have this:

```
var q = (from order in db.Orders
                        from payment in db.Payments
                        .Where(x => x.ID == order.paymentID)
                        .DefaultIfEmpty()
                        from siteUser in db.SiteUsers
                        .Where(x => x.siteUserID == order.siteUserID)
                        .DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where siteUser.siteUserID != null
                                                select new
                        {
                            order.orderID,
                            order.dateCreated,
                            payment.totalAmount,
                            siteUser.firstName,
                            siteUser.lastName
                        });
```

I want to add on to it like this:

```
switch (_qs["sort"])
            {
                case "0":
                    q = q.OrderByDescending(x => x.dateCreated);
                    break;
                case "1":
                    q = q.OrderBy(x => x.dateCreated);
                    break; ...
```

I've done this before with a single table, but the multiple tables in the first code block force me to specify a select statement which causes it to be an anonymous type. How can this be done?

Note: I even tried to make a class with the properties that i'm selecting and casting the query to this type, still a no go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question but the code you pasted looks valid to me.

I checked:

```
var q = (
    from order in db.Orders
    join payment in db.Payments on
        order.paymentID equals payment.ID into payments
    from payment in payments.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join siteUser in db.SiteUsers on
        order.siteUserID equals siteUser.siteUserID into siteUsers
    from siteUser in siteUsers.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where siteUser.siteUserID != null
    select
        new
        {
            order.orderID,
            order.dateCreated,
            payment.totalAmount,
            siteUser.firstName,
            siteUser.lastName
        });
switch (sort)
{
    case "0":
        q = q.OrderByDescending(x => x.dateCreated);
        break;
    case "1":
        q = q.OrderBy(x => x.dateCreated);
        break;
}
var restult = q.ToList();
```

This works.

Comment: @Nick - if this does not answer the question, please explain what is wrong.

Comment: Your right it does work... I'm not sure what I had before that wouldn't work. Thanks!